# How to simplify $\int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t (xyz) dx dy dz$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

During the integration of a highly symmetric integrand

$$ \int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t (xyz) dx dy dz$$

What manipulations can be done to reduce the above triple integral to just a single integral of for instance some function $f(w)$ of some variable $w$ such that

$$\int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t (xyz) dx dy dz = \int_{-t}^t f(w) dw $$

?

---

Attempt:

$ \int_{-t}^t x^3 (dx)^3$ misses many terms when $x,y,z$ have different values.

Comment: It is $\int_{-t}^{t} 0dw$ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just separate the integrals and write

$$\int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t \int_{-t}^t (xyz) dx dy dz = \int_{-t}^t x dx \int_{-t}^t ydy \int_{-t}^t zdz = \left(\int_{-t}^t x dx\right)^3  $$

Since

$$\int_{-t}^t x dx = \int_{-t}^t ydy = \int_{-t}^t zdz$$

Of course $$\int_{-t}^t x dx = 0$$ since you're integrating an odd function over a symmetrical interval around $0$ (or you can just compute it directly).